# How to post an Array from Textarea to mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, post

I'm trying to POST an Array of serial numbers, but once it's posted, all the serial numbers added in the textarea are posted together as a single String.

This is my form:

```
<form class="" id="serialsForm" action="/serialsnew" method="post">
 <h5 style="text-align:center">Procesar RMA</h5>

  <input placeholder="Product ID"class="input1" type="text" 
  name="productId" value="">

  <textarea id="textAreaSerial" class="newSeriales" placeholder="# 
  Seriales"name="serial[]" rows="3" cols="80" ng-trim="false"> . 
  </textarea>


  <button  type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary 
   buttonNewRma" data-toggle="modal"  id="submit">
  submit
  </button>

</form>
```

**this is my post request**

```
 app.post("/serialsnew", function(req, res){
 var productId = req.body.productId;
 var serialNum = req.body.serial;

Seriales.create({
 product: productId,
 seriales: serialNum,

  }, function(err, serial){
    if(err){
      console.log("we coulndt add the serial numbers")
     } else{
      console.log("we just added a patch of serials")
     }
  })
  res.json(req.body);
  // res.redirect("/serialsnew")
  })
```

This is how my array looks like on my res.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmpxt.png)

I'm trying to create an input of serial numbers so we can track warranty time. An example of how i would like to store the data is below.

```
{
productId: "laptops",
serial: [
11111,
22222, 
44444,
 ]
```

}

Comment: Please provide info on what is the desired output. Also you do not have to attach an image ... just type the object output and what is that you want to data to look like.

Comment: Hello @Akrion I just edited the post, i added how i would like to my params be stored on the database, i want to pass several  group of number in the textarea, and then they are stored as array in Serials. i hope this help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably happening because you're using a textarea, which is meant for string data.

How about modifying the data like this?

```js
//this is basically your req.body, with sample serial values
var req = {body: {serial:["2423,23423"]}};

var stringGroup = req.body.serial[0];
var serial = stringGroup.split(",").map(Number);

console.log(serial);
```

Comment: Ray Thank you very much, This solve that issue, just for curiosity, how do you suggest separating  several group of numbers on the text area? by comma, by enter or spaces?  example:
ex1: 4444,5555,6666
exp2: 44444 
           555555
           66666
exp3: 4444 55555 66666 

thanks

Comment: Welcome :) If you're talking about the visual aspect when showing data to the user, 'enter' separated values look neatest in a textarea. Assuming you have no more than 6 to 7 groups. Otherwise use commas. 
P.S. could you upvote my answer as well please? Upvotes contribute towards badges. Thanks to you as well :)

Comment: Hey Ray thanks for the tip, i tried to upvote but it doesn't let me, it says that votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly display score :( , but i did.
Would you mind putting a start on the question so my reputation goes up? thank you

Comment: Aah I see, no worries. Here you go!